# Django 1.5 and old syntax _(

Tags: django

I'm new to Django and looking at some old packages. I have 1.5 installed and see that one some of the older apps they use the syntax `_(`  a lot for example...

```
help_text=_(u'something')
```

What is this? Was it depreciated? Will it give me issues with 1.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is [`gettext`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gettext.html) for internationalizing an application

Django provides [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/) on their site.

according to the docs, In django 1.5 it is located at

`from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _`

It was not deprecated